# Java Script entering Script in String

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to echo information from a JS page into a SMS to be sent this is what I have currently

```
 $text = urlencode("$slfirstname $sllastname $slcustom1. Has activated a SOS Panic Button");
```

How can I run the script I have tried the following but gives me error

```
 $text = urlencode("$slfirstname $sllastname $slcustom1. Has activated a SOS Panic Button <script src="geo.js"></script>");
```

The end result I want to get is to get Longs and Lats from the PHP and JS to display in the $text section

This is the PHP code that echo's the info on the same page

```
 echo 'Latitude: '.$lat.' Longitude: '.$long.'<br />';
```

This is the JS code

```
// this calls the php script with the data we have collected from the geolocation lookup
function GEOajax(url) {
 xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
 xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// this reads the response from the php script and updates the page with it's output
function updatePage() {
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
  var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
  document.getElementById("geo").innerHTML = '' + response;
 }
}
```

Comment: you want to showing   ajax success msg in your page

Comment: I have it showing on the page but need to place the values inside the $text area that is part of an SMS being sent to a predefined numer. The ajax script is running on the same page as where the SMS is being formulated to be sent

Comment: urlencode will just give you a urlencoded string, it won't execute the `<script>geo.js</script>`. You have to explain in more depth what you actually want to achieve. Do you want to populate `$slfirstname, $sllastname, $slcustom1`, do you want to have the geo coordinates into `$text`? Without any real context it looks to me like you are doing it backwards.